# Sub-id, tracking-id or site-id within http://cj.com buyUrl

Tags: tracking, affiliate, commission-junction

someone knows about the possibility to add a request parameter indicating a tracking-id within cj.com affiliate program

I receive the following link:

```
http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-3631586-10557180?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.someshop.com
```

I want to put a subid between the parameters, for a future report track. i.e.:

```
http://www.jdoqocy.com/click-3631586-10557180?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.someshop.com&subid=ABC
```

Someone knows about this way to track with custom labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following page, describing the possible tracking style for some sites:

http://subids.tracking202.com

[]'s,

And Past

Answer (score 3):

I know this was asked a few years ago.  But in case someone stumbles upon this...

Query string parameter sid=YourCustomIdHere.  (I think it must be an integer if I remember correctly).